# Finding intersections of huge sets with huge dicts

Tags: python

I have a dict with 50,000,000 keys (strings) mapped to a count of that key (which is a subset of one with billions).

I also have a series of objects with a class set member containing a few thousand strings that may or may not be in the dict keys.

I need the fastest way to find the intersection of each of these sets.

Right now, I do it like this code snippet below:

```
for block in self.blocks:
    #a block is a python object containing the set in the thousands range
    #block.get_kmers() returns the set
    count = sum([kmerCounts[x] for x in block.get_kmers().intersection(kmerCounts)])
    #kmerCounts is the dict mapping millions of strings to ints
```

From my tests so far, this takes about 15 seconds per iteration. Since I have around 20,000 of these blocks, I am looking at half a week just to do this. And that is for the 50,000,000 items, not the billions I need to handle...

(And yes I should probably do this in another language, but I also need it done fast and I am not very good at non-python languages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to do a full intersection, you just want the matching elements from the big dictionary *if they exist*. If an element doesn't exist you can substitute `0` and there will be no effect on the sum. There's also no need to convert the input of `sum` to a list.

```
count = sum(kmerCounts.get(x, 0) for x in block.get_kmers())
```

Comment: That took it from days to under a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets around your list comprehension to turn it into a generator expression:

```
sum(kmerCounts[x] for x in block.get_kmers().intersection(kmerCounts))
```

That will save you some time and some memory, which may in turn reduce swapping, if you're experiencing that.

There is a lower bound to how much you can optimize here.  Switching to another language may ultimately be your only option.